# I want to get the index again on the script

Tags: jquery

I want to check the index value again.But to me ,my code only can make it once

```
$(function() {
    $('.tree').on("click", 'a',function(e) {
        var top = $(this).closest('tr').index()
        var cont = $(this).closest('tr').html()
      //  alert(cont)
        if ( top === 1) {
            alert('it is top')
            return false
            top = $(this).index()
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').empty()
            $('.second').before('<tr class="tree">'+ cont + '</tr>')
            top = $(this).index()
        }
    })
})
```

And I put the code on the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/gjypb/
maybe I need "for" to make it work.

Comment: what if you change `$(this).index()` with `$('this').index()` ?

Comment: what are you trying to do ??

Comment: @zzlalani and what's `$('this')` ?

Comment: sorry i thought the `$(this).index()` is not working..

Comment: @zzlalani I  get the element's index to judge the element is the "top" when the table have many tr,to change their position though by the button "a", and "click" to my code only can work once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.tree').on("click", 'a',function(e) {
        var top = $(this).closest('tr').index()
        var cont = $(this).closest('tr').html()
      //  alert(cont)
        if ( top === 1) {
            alert('it is top')
            top = $(this).index()
            return false // you were returning before the index() stmt
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').empty()
            $('.second').before('<tr class="tree">'+ cont + '</tr>')
            top = $(this).index()
        }
    })
})
```

But what you may need is

```
$(function() {
    $('table').on("click", 'a',function(e) {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr'), table = tr.closest('table');
        tr.insertBefore(table.find('tr').eq(1));
        return false;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eq4a4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m2DKL/)**

```
$(function() {
        $('table').on("click", '.tree a',function(e) {
            var top = $(this).closest('tr').index()
            var cont = $(this).closest('tr').html()
          //  alert(cont)
            console.log(top);
            if ( top === 1) {
                alert('it is top')
                return false
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').empty()
                $('.second').before('<tr class="tree">'+ cont + '</tr>')
            }
        })
})
```

The problem is that you are removing and adding `tr` after dom. By using a element that didn't change you can (with `.on()`) target `.tree` again.

Comment: If I have more tr element, I want though the button a to change their position, in my brain,I think the method to judge the index can make it right.But when I use the jsfiddle's code to use my project, things like not good.The question is when I make the element top,but another one make himself top,and the event won't work again.some code from my project: http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/Ga7fD/